# Symfony load translations dynamically

Tags: symfony, localization, internationalization, translation, multilingual

I need to load and override translations dynamically based on some user settings, the system I need is actually a combination of translations and string overrides, I tried having overrides `xliff` files for different user groups and loading them with

```
$this->translator->addResource('xlf', $path, $lang);
```

but with that I have caching issues, it doesn't seem appropriate to delete translation caches all the time, is there any better way to achieve this?

The big picture is that I need to support multiple languages, but there is a separate translations team (unaware of the technical implementation), and they need to be able to provide slightly different translations/texts to different user groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up deleting translations caches after all, this is the simplest way to do it, I might explore how to delete it less aggressively etc. in the future

```
$fileSystem = new Filesystem();
$fileSystem->remove("$this->cacheDir/translations");
```

(`$this->cacheDir` is `"%kernel.cache_dir%"` injected by DI into the service)